# Abstraction to extract data from JSON in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I am looking for a good abstraction to extract data form JSON (I am using `json4s` now).

Suppose I have a case class `A` and data in JSON format.

```
case class A(a1: String, a2: String, a3: String)

{"a1":"xxx", "a2": "yyy", "a3": "zzz"}
```

I need a function to extract the JSON data and return `A` with these data as follows:

```
val a: JValue => A = ...
```

I do not want to write the function `a` from scratch. I would rather *compose* it from primitive functions.

For example, I can write a primitive function to extract string by field name:

```
val str: (String, JValue) => String = {(fieldName, jval) => ... }
```

Now I would like to *compose* the function `a: JValue => A` from `str`. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Well... I am not sure if this is relevant but If you use PlayJson... then it provides Scala Macros to get this kind of job done very easily.

Comment: Argonaut, providing easy codec for case classes and also cursor for custom handling.

Comment: @cchantep Sounds interesting. Could you please give an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider use of [Play-JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaJson), which has a [composable](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.7/ScalaJsonCombinators) "Reads" object.  If you've ever used ReactiveMongo, it can be used in much the same way.  Contrary to some older posts here, it can be used stand-alone, without most of the rest of Play.

It uses the common "implicit translator" (my term) idiom.  I found that my favorite deserializing pattern for using it is not highlighted in the docs, though - the pattern they espouse is a lot harder to get right, IMHO.  I make heavy use of .as and .asOpt, which are documented on the first linked page above, in the small section "Using JsValue.as/asOpt".  When deserializing a JSON object, you can say something like

```
val person:Person = (someParsedJsonObject \ "aPerson").as[Person]
```

and as long as you have an implicit Reads[Person] in scope, all just works.  There are built-in Reads for all primitive types and many collection types.  In many cases, it makes sense to put the Reads and Writes implicit objects in the companion object for, e.g., Person.

I thought json4s had a similar feature, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You're right, json4s has very similar functionality, but I think it can serialize/deserialize most case classes without the user providing any implicits. Not sure if it's any better overall than Play-JSON though.

Comment: @RichHenry -  Play-JSON can do case classes without implicits too - but for me, at least, there's always some little extra thing I need that makes the automatic mapping useless - so I didn't mention it. That's not due to any shortcoming of the automatic mapping, other than it not being able to read my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Argonaut is fully functional Scala library.

It allows to [encode/decode case classes](http://argonaut.io/doc/codec/) (JSON codecs).

```scala
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

implicit def PersonDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Person]
  jdecode2L(Person.apply)("name", "age")
  // Codec for Person case class from JSON of form
  // { "name": "string", "age": 1 }
```

It also provides JSON cursor (lenses/monocle) for custom parsing.

```scala
implicit def PersonDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Person] =
  DecodeJson(c => for {
    name <- (c --\ "_name").as[String]
    age <- (c --\ "_age").as[String].map(_.toInt)
  } yield Person(name, age))
  // Decode Person from a JSON with property names different
  // from those of the case class, and age passed as string:
  // { "_name": "string", "age": "10" }
```

Parsing result is represented by [DecodeResult](http://argonaut.io/scaladocs/#argonaut.DecodeResult) type that can be composed (`.map`, `.flatMap`) and handle error cases.

Comment: Thank you. `Argonaut` looks promising but I don't like their DSL syntax (e.g. `--\ `). I would like also to compose the parser (decoding) functions rather than the results. Maybe `lenses` are the abstraction I am looking for ..

Comment: Argonaut as some (a lot) of features like that. I would suggest to look at the scaladoc.